# Pole and polar of Circle

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates

I am studying circle of class $12th$ level. I've come to a concept of pole and polar for circle.

**Definition of pole and polar**

Let $P$ be any point inside or outside the circle. Draw any chord $AB$ and $A'B'$  passing through $P$. If tangents to the circle at $A$ and $B$ meet at $Q$, then locus of $Q$ is called the polar of $P$ with respect to circle and $P$ is called the pole and if tangents to the circle at $A'$ and $B'$ meet at $Q'$, then the straight line $QQ'$ is polar with $P$ as its pole.

**In one book while solving problem I come to know other definition of pole and polar and it goes like:**

Suppose $OX$ is a fixed line on which O is a fixed point. Suppose $P$ is a point such that OP=r and anticlockwise angle $XOP$ = $\theta$ , then we define $(r,\theta)$ as polar coordinates of a point $P$, $O$ is called pole and line $OX$ is called initial line.

I want know that are those two definitions represent same thing?

if yes, then will be please elaborate?
and if no, then why someone did not name them differently.
I just want to clear my confusion.

**[image]I am attaching image from my book for reference.**

Comment: No. The first definition comes from projective geometry, while the second definition is related to polar coordinates.

Comment: They are different.  Typically you know which is which because of context. The same as for natural language, no one person is in charge of terminology, which might explain why nobody named them differently.